# How to get version history of a SharePoint list item in to PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerbi

I have a SharePoint (V.2016) Online List on which a PowerApp application is developed. The App is like of Approvals/Rejection timelines etc. For Audit trail we can go to the specific item in to the SharePoint list and can see who has made what changes. But i want those details to be fetched in a PowerApp Screen. Can anyone please help that how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve version history of SharePoint list item using Power Automate.

Refer [this](https://www.about365.nl/2019/08/08/view-sharepoint-item-version-history-in-powerapps/) article having step by step explanation to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Diksha, Thanks for the reference. I will try that by next week and will get back with the results. Regards,

Comment: You're welcome @AkshayManke. Yes share your result once done.
Also please upvote and accept the answer if it answers to your question.